# Converting Mac terminal command to windows console command

Tags: windows, macos, console

I have the following in the OSX terminal

```
printf "TRIGGER\r\n" | nc 192.000.0.000 8000
```

How would I duplicate this functionality, but in the Windows console?

Comment: By downloading a Win32 version of netcat.

Comment: what about printf  ??

Comment: `echo TRIGGER| nc 192.000.0.000 8000`.